# How to combine django-ckeditor upload path with ImageField upload path

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

Model:

```
content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="news/%Y/%m")
```

I set this in settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'news/%Y/%m'
```

But the images still go to different folders.Is there anyway to make two paths one?

Best regards!

Comment: in the model, you do not need ```image```. The ```content``` will have all images. Those uploaded images will go to ```CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH ```.